# Margin: Auto wont work in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Wonder if anyone can help me I am trying to centre a div with another div on a HTML page. The first div will centre fine, but no matter what i do with the div inside the parent div will not centre using 'margin:auto' in my CSS.

Below is my HTML:-

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">

  </div>
</div>
```

and here is my CSS:-

```
.jumbotron {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: #5a9a9a;
}

.jumbotron .container {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;    
    background-color: #5a5a5a;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: if you change `.jumbotron .container` to `position: relative;` it centers horizontally. Vertical centering would take more, if you need that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `position: absolute;` from `.jumbotron .container`

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ac2j6wt1/) to demonstrate.

Comment: And zgood beat me by 6 seconds. Questions like this turn into a typing race.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position:absolute;` from `.jumbotron .container`

margin auto will not work with absolutely positioned elements

Answer (score 1):

take out

```
position: absolute;
```

on

```
.jumboptron .container
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `position: absolute`. As you can see that `absolute` has to be positioned using actual percentages or pixels.

Now I made a little [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nctzqLeg/) for you to see.

Answer (score 1):

The `margin: auto` works only on `static`ly positioned elements. So either remove `position: absolute;` from your `.jumboptron .container`, or use:

```
.jumbotron .container {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #5a5a5a;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -250px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. But the problem is that I want the child div to be relative to the parent class i.e. I want it to be in the centre of the parent div, not in the centre of the page. So if I remove the 'position: relative' from the child div that would mean the child div ignores the positioning of the parent div?

Comment: think Ive been staring at this too long. Think Ive sorted it. Again thanks for the help :-)